# problème with download in published site ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, publish, ms-publisher

I have a problem with action download in an ASP.NET MVC application, in the dev machine it works without any problém, but when i publish the application to IIS or when i test from the test server, i have nothing no error no exception, i have only white window with at the bottom of the page 'witing for localhost...'

My controller action

```
public ActionResult DownloadDocument(int idDocument)
    {
        try
        {
            DocumentVM Document = ServiceApplicatif.getDocumentById(idDocument);
            //Get document from virtual path
            string FileName = ServiceFileUtilities.GetFileById(Document.StreamId);

            DownloadResult drs = new DownloadResult //it's a file and it works
            {
                RootPath = rootDocuments, //rootDocuments is a path to filetable
                ContentLength = Document.Length,
                ContentType = Document.MimeType,
                FileDownloadName = FileName,
                FileName = FileName
            };

            return drs;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erreur : " + ex.message.toString());
        }
    }
```

My view is simple with

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

And my JQuery function

```
 function myFunction() {
        var pageURL = url; //url with idDocument which is right
        OpenPopupCenter(url, 'myWin', 600, 800);
    }

    function OpenPopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
        var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
        var top = (screen.height - h) / 4;  // for 25% - devide by 4  |  for 33% - devide by 3
        var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no,adressbar=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        targetWin.document.title = "Document";
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you call URL directly from browser?
Also, in which browser you are testing?

Comment: "Waiting for localhost" means that the browser receives no response from the server, which may have crashed or finished execution without sending anything back.

Comment: Well if there is "Waiting for localhost" then your download URL is definitely wrong and does not point to production server.

Comment: Thnaks for your reply. So how explain that in dev machine the server send me back the file with the correct mimetype and all property.

Comment: @Dusan When i call URL it show 'Page Web inaccessible'

Comment: That is simple. The dev machine is on localhost, you request download from localhost URL and everything works fine. Now, you publish the application on the test server and instead from downloading file from www.yourtestserver.com you are trying to download from localhost - which is wrong and you pageURL is definutelly wrong.

Comment: Just show me how do you generate `pageURL` for the javascript and I will tell you what are you doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The probléme was thrown by the application pool identity, You should ​​assigned a user with grant on the machine server